# How do you use re-size all Graphic2D

Tags: java, swing, jframe, render, image-resizing

In java how can you make a game fully realizable! But so logic and graphics can work with it? I have tried using SCALE methods. But this doesn't allow perfect full-screen for every computer. So I made this:

```
    public void resize(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, boolean UNDECORATED) {

          frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
          frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
          frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

          this.WIDTH = WIDTH;
          this.HEIGHT = HEIGHT;
          frame.setUndecorated(UNDECORATED);
          frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      }
```

So you can set your screen size to whatever you want! It works but the graphics will not work with it? Is there a way in Graphics2D to stretch all the graphics so it fits? For example if there was a method that existed like:

```
            G2D.resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Image.NEAREST_PARENT_RESCALE);
```

Any idea?

**Things I have tried:**

- Drawing all graphics to a Buffered-image then drawing that Image onto the screen size.
- Just using SCALE and doing WIDTH * SCALE etc.
- Lots of math

**Things I do not mind**

- If you have a WIDE-SCREEN it stretches graphic2D objects to the size.
- If you have a SQUARE-SCREEN it squishes graphics2D objects to the size.

So how can I make a perfectly resealable game using Graphics2D, JFrame.

Comment: `Lots of math` + `SCALE and doing WIDTH * SCALE` + `frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);` == for better help sooner post an `SSCCE`/`MCVE`, short, runnable, compilable, but by default (methods in `LayoutManager`) child rreturn its size back to container, then everything is (`Lots of math` + `SCALE and doing WIDTH * SCALE`) about `getHeight`/`Weight`

Comment: drawing to a `BufferedImage` of a fixed size and then drawing it to the screen like `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, null)` doesn't do the job?

Comment: @Dima Maligin It does its just not as effective as some other methods. But I have found a effective method. Feel free to use it. There is just problems when doing that method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the most generic form, one can consider this as a classical problem of graphics programming, namely, as the transformation from **world coordinates** to **screen coordinates**. You have an object that has a size of "1.0 x 1.0" in your world coordinate system (regardless of which *unit* this has). And this object should be painted so that it has a size of, for example, "600 pixels * 600 pixels" on the screen.

Broadly speaking, there are at least three options to achieve this in Swing:

- You can draw into an image, and then draw a scaled version of the image
- You can draw into a scaled `Graphics2D` object
- You can draw scaled objects

Each of this has possible advantages and disadvantages, and hidden caveats.

### Drawing into an image, and drawing a scaled version of the image:

This might look like a simple solution, but has a potential drawback: The image itself has a certain resolution (size). If the image is too small, and you are scaling it up to fill the screen, it may appear blocky. If the image is too large, and you are scaling it down to fit into the screen, pixels of the image may be lost.

In both cases, there are several tuning parameters for the process of scaling the image. In fact, scaling an image is far more tricky than it looks at the first glance. For details, one may refer to the article [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983611) by Chris Campbell.

### Drawing into a scaled `Graphics2D` object

The [`Graphics2D` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) already offers the full functionality that is necessary to create the transformation between the *world coordinate system* and the *screen coordinate system*. This is accomplished by the `Graphics2D` class by internally storing an [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html), which describes this transformation. This `AffineTransform` may be modified directly via the `Graphics2D` object:

```
void paintSomething(Graphics2D g) {
    ...
    g.draw(someShape);

    // Everything that is painted after this line will
    // be painted 3 times as large: 
    g.scale(3.0, 3.0);

    g.draw(someShape); // Will be drawn larger 
}
```

Some care has to be taken to properly manage the transform that is stored in the `Graphics2D` object. In general, one should create a backup of the original `AffineTransform` before applying additional transformations, and restore this original transform afterwards:

```
// Create a backup of the original transform
AffineTransform oldAT = g.getTransform();

// Apply some transformations
g.scale(3.0, 4.0);
g.translate(10.0, 20.0);

// Do custom painting the the transformed graphics
paintSomething(g):

// Restore the original transformation
g.setTransform(oldAT);
```

(Another advice for the last method: The [`Graphics2D#setTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setTransform-java.awt.geom.AffineTransform-) method should  **never** be used to apply a new coordinate transform on top of an existing transform. It is solely intended for restoring an "old" transform, as shown in this example (and in the documentation of this method)).

One potential drawback of scaling with the `Graphics2D` class is that afterwards, **everything** will be scaled. Particularly, this scaling will **also** affect line widths (that is, the width of the [Stroke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Stroke.html)). For example, consider a sequence of calls like this one:

```
// By default, this will paint a line with a width (stroke) of 1.0:
g.draw(someLine);

// Apply some scaling...
g.scale(10.0, 10.0);

// Now, this will paint the same line, but with a width of 10. 
g.draw(someLine);
```

The second call will cause a line to be drawn that is 10 pixels wide. This may not be desired in many cases. This effect can be avoided with the third alternative:

### Drawing scaled objects

The transformation between the *world coordinate system* and the *screen coordinate system* can also be maintained manually. It is convenient to represent this as an [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html). The `AffineTransform` class can be used to create transformed versions of `Shape` object, that can then be drawn directly into an (**un**-transformed) `Graphics2D` object. This is accomplished with the [`AffineTransform#createTransformedShape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape-java.awt.Shape-) method:

```
void paintSomething(Graphics2D g) {
    ...
    // Draw some shape in its normal size
    g.draw(someShape);

    // Create a scaling transform
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(3.0, 3.0);

    // Create a scaled version of the shape
    Shape transformedShape = at.createTransformedShape(someShape);

    // Draw the scaled shape
    g.draw(transformedShape);
}
```

This is probably the most versatile approach. The only potential drawback is that, when *many* small, simple shapes are drawn, this will cause many, small temporary transformed shapes to be created, which may cause reduced performance. (There are ways to alleviate this problem, but detailed performance considerations and optimizations are beyond the scope of this answer).

---

### Summary

The follwing image shows the comparison of all approaches. Some example objects (represented as `Shape` objects) are drawn. Each row compares the three different scaling methods mentioned above. With their "default" size, the objects fill a rectangle in world coordinates that has a size of 100x100. In the first two rows, they are scaled up to fill an area on the screen of 190x190 pixels. In the last two rows, they are scaled down to fill an area on the screen of 60x60 pixels. (These sizes have been chosen in order to have some "odd" scaling factors of 1.9 and 0.6. Certain effects (artifacts) may not appear when the scaling factors are whole numbers, or exactly 0.5, for example).

For the upscaling and the downscaling, there additionally is a comparison between the "standard" way of painting, and "high quality" painting (indicated by the "(HQ)" in the title of each panel). The "high quality" here simply means that the rendering hints

```
KEY_ANTIALIAS = VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
KEY_RENDERING = VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY
```

have been set:

[image: ScalingMethods]

Here is the corresponding program, as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ScalingMethodComparison
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        Dimension larger = new Dimension(190,190);
        Dimension smaller = new Dimension(60,60);

        f.getContentPane().add(createPanel(larger, false));
        f.getContentPane().add(createPanel(larger, true));
        f.getContentPane().add(createPanel(smaller, false));
        f.getContentPane().add(createPanel(smaller, true));

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel createPanel(Dimension d, boolean highQuality)
    {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
        for (ScalingMethodComparisonPanel.ScalingMethod scalingMethod : 
            ScalingMethodComparisonPanel.ScalingMethod.values())
        {
            p.add(createPanel(d, scalingMethod, highQuality));
        }
        return p;
    }

    private static JPanel createPanel(
        Dimension d, ScalingMethodComparisonPanel.ScalingMethod scalingMethod, 
        boolean highQuality)
    {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
            scalingMethod.toString()+(highQuality?" (HQ)":"")));
        JPanel scalingMethodComparisonPanel = 
            new ScalingMethodComparisonPanel(
                createObjects(), d, scalingMethod, highQuality);
        p.add(scalingMethodComparisonPanel);
        return p;
    }

    // Returns a list of objects that should be drawn, 
    // occupying a rectangle of 100x100 in WORLD COORDINATES
    private static List<Shape> createObjects()
    {
        List<Shape> objects = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        objects.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(10,10,80,80));
        objects.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(20,20,60,60));
        objects.add(new Line2D.Double(30,30,70,70));
        return objects;
    }
}


class ScalingMethodComparisonPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static final Color COLORS[] = {
        Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE,
    };

    enum ScalingMethod
    {
        SCALING_IMAGE,
        SCALING_GRAPHICS,
        SCALING_SHAPES,
    }

    private final List<Shape> objects;
    private final ScalingMethod scalingMethod;
    private final boolean highQuality;

    private final Dimension originalSize = new Dimension(100,100);
    private final Dimension scaledSize;

    private BufferedImage image;

    public ScalingMethodComparisonPanel(
        List<Shape> objects,
        Dimension scaledSize,
        ScalingMethod scalingMethod,
        boolean highQuality)
    {
        this.objects = objects;
        this.scaledSize = new Dimension(scaledSize);
        this.scalingMethod = scalingMethod;
        this.highQuality = highQuality;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(scaledSize);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());

        if (highQuality)
        {
            g.setRenderingHint( 
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        }

        if (scalingMethod == ScalingMethod.SCALING_IMAGE)
        {
            paintByScalingImage(g);
        }
        else if (scalingMethod == ScalingMethod.SCALING_GRAPHICS)
        {
            paintByScalingGraphics(g);
        }
        else if (scalingMethod == ScalingMethod.SCALING_SHAPES)
        {
            paintByScalingShapes(g);
        }
    }

    private void paintByScalingImage(Graphics2D g)
    {
        if (image == null)
        {
            image = new BufferedImage(
                originalSize.width, originalSize.height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        Graphics2D ig = image.createGraphics();
        paintObjects(ig, null);
        ig.dispose();

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height, null);
    }

    private void paintByScalingGraphics(Graphics2D g)
    {
        AffineTransform oldAT = g.getTransform();
        double scaleX = (double)scaledSize.width / originalSize.width;
        double scaleY = (double)scaledSize.height / originalSize.height;
        g.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
        paintObjects(g, null);
        g.setTransform(oldAT);
    }

    private void paintByScalingShapes(Graphics2D g)
    {
        double scaleX = (double)scaledSize.width / originalSize.width;
        double scaleY = (double)scaledSize.height / originalSize.height;
        AffineTransform at = 
            AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scaleX, scaleY);
        paintObjects(g, at);
    }



    private void paintObjects(Graphics2D g, AffineTransform at)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<objects.size(); i++)
        {
            Shape shape = objects.get(i);
            g.setColor(COLORS[i%COLORS.length]);
            if (at == null)
            {
                g.draw(shape);
            }
            else
            {
                g.draw(at.createTransformedShape(shape));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java Q's don't get enough attention anymore ;) Thanks for this superb answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite easy in Java. In a `Graphics2d` environment, the logical coordinate system (the coordinates you use in the drawing routines) and the physical coordinate system (the coordinates as they appear) on the screen are completely unrelated. Every time you draw onto a `Graphics2d` object, the logical coordinates are first translated to the physical coordinates by an `AffineTransform` object, and this `AffineTransform` object can be modified. For this you can use the `Graphics2D.scale(double,double)`, `Graphics2D.rotate(double)`, `Graphics2D.translate(double,double)` and `Graphics2D.shear(double,double)` methods.

So if you first call

```
g2d.scale(2.0,2.0);
```

then all your graphics that you subsequently draw will be twice as large in both directions.

Comment: @Marco13 I must have been thinking about something else, cause I believe you're right. The question would then come down to which direction you would scale (ie do you favor the width or height of the target), but that's probably beyond the scope of the question

Comment: This is working quite well. Is there a way to change the Algorithm that it renders it in? Like one for Quality? Or this that Rendering Hints in graphics?

Comment: @Macro13 Sure, if you could turn it into a answer that would be useful. For the database, and for reference. Also its RenderingHints that is exactly what I thought. Thanks for everyone's help, alot-of pepole get this problem. - Elliot Bewey

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly all you want is to draw your graphics in different resolutions without removing or adding any content.

Well one of the "things you have tried" can do that.

Drawing to a fixed size `BufferedImage` will ensure that all your components are visible within that `BufferedImage` (assuming you draw them correctly and relative to it's fixed size) then you can just draw the image to your flexible size screen.

Here's a full runnable code example that does that:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    // fixed size for the image
    private static final int WIDTH = 640;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 480;

    private BufferedImage image;
    private boolean running;
    private Thread t;

    public Test(Dimension dims) {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(dims); // actual screen size
        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        running = false;
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (running)
            return;
        t = new Thread(this);
        running = true;
        t.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (!running)
            return;
        running = false;
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                t.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void render() {
        // draw to your image
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics().create();
        g2d.fillRect((WIDTH / 2) - 25, (HEIGHT / 2) - 25, 50, 50);
        g2d.dispose();

        // draw the image to your screen
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        g2d = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics().create();
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        g2d.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public void run() {
        // approximately sync rendering to 60 FPS don't use it as it is.
        // there are much better ways to do this.
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long frameTime = 1000 / 60;
        long tick = 0;
        while (running) {
            while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) > tick) {
                render();
                tick += frameTime;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test(new Dimension(800, 600));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fit to screen");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                test.stop();
                frame.dispose();
                super.windowClosing(e);
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(test);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                test.start();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is only a quick implementation there are things that can be done better in that code bu you get the picture. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I will use some of the code you have wrote in future projects. This was basically what I was doing. But it created problems further ahead in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help :

Scaling graphics2D that contains basic shapes has a drawback : thickness of lines are doubled if the scale is doubled, that's a problem in an application implementing a zoom feature...
The only way I found is to make the preferred size of the container bigger and then, draw the shapes.

Here's a zoom function using mouse wheel and the pixel of the object pointed by the mouse stays under the mouse pointer.
It took me a long time to figure out how to do that properly, but I finally found out...(the application is an astrolabe and I wanted to zoom in and out)

The graphics2D belongs to a JPanel that is contained in the bottom part of a JSplitPane :

```
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

Dimension dim = new Dimension(), oldDim = this.getPreferredSize();
double newX, newY;
Rectangle rect, oldRect;
    
if(this.mousewheel >= 0){
  this.mousewheel += -e.getWheelRotation() * this.mousewheelSensibility;
}
else {
  this.mousewheel = 0;
}

dim.setSize(this.astro.splitBottomDimension.getWidth() + this.mousewheel, this.astro.splitBottomDimension.getHeight() + this.mousewheel);

oldRect = this.getVisibleRect();
    
this.mouseX = e.getX();
this.mouseY = e.getY();
this.setPreferredSize(dim);

newX = this.mouseX / oldDim.getWidth() * dim.getWidth();
newY = this.mouseY / oldDim.getHeight() * dim.getHeight();
rect = new Rectangle((int)newX - (this.mouseX - oldRect.x), (int)newY - (this.mouseY - oldRect.y), oldRect.width, oldRect.height);

this.scrollRectToVisible(rect); 
    
this.revalidate();
```

Comment: Generally, you draw the largest possible image and shrink it to fit.  This avoids blurring, although as you said, you have to take line thickness into account.

Comment: Indeed, but in my case, it's not an image, only shapes, but even with shapes, the scale function isn't appropriate for a zoom in/out feature, well, I read Marco13's post and he talks about KEY_ANTIALIAS = VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON and KEY_RENDERING = VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY, maybe I could have done the job differently, not sure about that...

Comment: You draw shapes on the largest possible `BufferedImage`.  You then shrink the image to fit.