# How to implement resize element when zoom in

Tags: java

I've implemented a JPanel with Java Swing to visualize a map. The map contains nodes and links. I would like to resize nodes/links when zooming.

```
public class MainJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private List<Station> stations;
private List<Node> micro_nodes;
private List<Link> micro_links;

private double scale = 1.0;
private double translateX;
private double translateY;
private int referenceX;
private int referenceY;

public MainJPanel() {
    initComponents();  
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    /*Zooming*/
    zooming(g2d);

    AffineTransform saveTransform = g2d.getTransform();
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(saveTransform);


    /*The panning transformation*/
    at.translate(translateX, translateY);
    g2d.setTransform(at);


    drawLayer(g2d, stations, null, Color.BLUE, null, at);
    drawLayer(g2d, micro_nodes, micro_links, Color.GREEN, Color.GRAY, at);

    g2d.setTransform(saveTransform);

}

private void zooming(Graphics2D g2d) {
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();

    g2d.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
    g2d.scale(scale, scale);
    g2d.translate(-w / 2, -h / 2);
}

private void drawLayer(Graphics2D g2d,  List nodes, List<Link> edges, Color nodeColor, Color edgeColor, AffineTransform at) {

        if (edges != null) {
            for (Link edge : edges) {
                g2d.setColor(edgeColor);
                drawEdge(g2d, edge.getCoord(), at);
            }
        }
        for (Object node : nodes) {
            g2d.setColor(nodeColor);
            drawNode(g2d, node, at);
        }
}

private void drawEdge(Graphics2D g2d, double coord[], AffineTransform at) {

    Point2D startCoord = CoordinateConvertor.convertLatLongToCoord(new Point2D.Double(coord[0], coord[1]), getWidth(), getHeight());
    Point2D endCoord = CoordinateConvertor.convertLatLongToCoord(new Point2D.Double(coord[2], coord[3]), getWidth(), getHeight());

    Line2D.Double l = new Line2D.Double(startCoord.getX(), startCoord.getY(), endCoord.getX(), endCoord.getY());
    Shape transformedShape = at.createTransformedShape(l);
    g2d.draw(transformedShape);

}

private void drawNode(Graphics2D g2d, Object node, AffineTransform at) {
    Point2D p2d = null;
    if (node instanceof Station) {
        p2d = CoordinateConvertor.convertLatLongToCoord(((Station) node).getCoordinates(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    if (node instanceof Node) {
        p2d = CoordinateConvertor.convertLatLongToCoord(((Node) node).getCoordinates(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    if (p2d != null) {
        Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double(p2d.getX() - 2, p2d.getY() - 2, 4, 4);
        Shape transformedShape = at.createTransformedShape(e);
        g2d.draw(transformedShape);

    }
}

public static Point2D convertLatLongToCoord(Point2D coordinate, int width, int height) {
    double xPixel = Math.abs((MAX_RIGHT - coordinate.getX()) / (MAX_RIGHT - MAX_LEFT) * width - width);
    double yPixel = Math.abs(((MAX_DOWN - coordinate.getY())) / (MAX_DOWN - MAX_TOP) * height - height);
    return new Point2D.Double(xPixel, yPixel);
}
```

This is the original map:

[image: Map]

This is the map after zooming in:

[image: Zoom Map]

How can I resize the nodes/links when zooming? This is what I want:

[image: What I want]

Comment: Zooming and panning/scrolling may be a bit fiddly. The question is thus *very* broad. It's not clear whether you want a scroll pane, or a view-based functionality. In any case, quite a while ago I built https://github.com/javagl/Viewer , maybe you find it interesting.

Comment: Sorry about inaccurate information. I updated post. Thanks for your code I'll check it.

Comment: This is still not really clear. Do you mean that the *size* of the nodes and links (i.e. the size of the green circles and the thickness of the lines) should not change when you zoom?

Comment: Positon of node is identified by GPS (latitude/longitude). For example some node is very close to another node. I want regulate size of nodes and links when zoom. I added picture what I want and my function from Lat/Lon to XY.

Comment: Then this is nearly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439225/how-do-you-use-re-size-all-graphic2d . Have a look at the section "Drawing scaled objects" in my answer there. You have to compute the positions of the nodes *in the zoomed state*, and always draw them using a `Graphics2D` object that is **not** scaled (i.e. you may **not** call `g.scale(x,y)`). In fact, you might consider using a real graph library, like http://jung.sourceforge.net/ or http://jgrapht.org/ . Otherwise, it might help if you added a bit of your `drawLayer` code...

Comment: What do you get and what is wrong with it?

Comment: @matt My interpretation right now is: When zooming in (e.g. by using `g.scale(2,2)`), then the circles are larger and the lines are thicker. And I think that he wants the size+thickness to remain constant, as indicated in the last picture. This is the crucial difference between "Drawing with a scaled graphics" and "Drawing scaled objects" that I pointed out in my answer to the question linked above, and in my https://github.com/javagl/Viewer library. (But maybe I still misunderstood the question...)

Comment: @Marco13 Many thanks I'try it. I added draw layer.

Comment: Is the part invloving the `AffineTransform` an attempt of a solution?

Comment: Yes but still not working. I try to understand your solution.